# launching skype on desktop keeps asking for admin user rights then reinstalls every time

Tags: windows-7, skype

I use Skype in a networked institution. Anytime I try to open Skype, there is a popup to enter network administrator credentials before I can launch. After entering these credentials and moving on, the app then reinstalls all over again. It reinstalls every time one tries to launch it. The account is not wiped though. This usually happens with the new versions (Skype 8 and above). The older versions also give a "skype cannot connect" error. Only a user with admin privileges can run Skype without having to enter credentials.

Can I please have some help with this issue? All of us have this issue.

Comment: I would uninstall Skype, then install it again with Administrator permissions, it sounds it wasn't installed properly.  If everyone in your institution is having the problem, contacting an Administrator, is likely the best path forward.

Comment: It used to happen to me a lot. I had to use either https://portableapps.com/apps/internet/sportable or https://turbo.net/run/microsoft/skype. Until I moved on.

Comment: I installed with admin permissions as well. it worked well for about 1-2 weeks then back to the same issue again...I think I would go for the skype portable option. thanks a lot.